# Rookio Ceph cluster : mon c is low on available space message

Tags: kubernetes, ceph

I have setup `RookIO 1.4` cluster in Kubernetes 1.18.  with 3 nodes allocated 1TB storage on each of them.
after creating cluster. when I run the `ceph status` cluster status shows as `HEALTH_WARN` with `mon c is low on available space`.

There is no data stored yet. why status how low on available space? How to clear this error?

```
[root@rook-ceph-tools-6bdcd78654-sfjvl /]#  ceph  status
  cluster:
    id:     ad42764d-aa28-4da5-a828-2d87205aff08
    health: HEALTH_WARN
            mon c is low on available space

  services:
    mon: 3 daemons, quorum a,b,c (age 37m)
    mgr: a(active, since 36m)
    osd: 3 osds: 3 up (since 37m), 3 in (since 37m)

  data:
    pools:   1 pools, 1 pgs
    objects: 0 objects, 0 B
    usage:   3.0 GiB used, 3.6 TiB / 3.6 TiB avail
    pgs:     1 active+clean
```

All three node has same size storage:

```
sdb                                                                                                    8:16   0  1.2T  0 disk
└─ceph--a6cd601d--7584--4b1f--bf82--48c95437f351-osd--data--ae1bc856--8ded--4b1e--8c87--30ca0f0959a3 253:3    0  1.2T  0 lvm
sdb                                                                                                    8:16   0  1.2T  0 disk
└─ceph--ccaf7144--d6a0--441c--bcd5--6a09d056bd7a-osd--data--36a9b28c--7207--400a--936b--edfb3255ce0b 253:3    0  1.2T  0 lvm
sdb                                                                                                    8:16   0  1.2T  0 disk
└─ceph--53e9b8a9--8925--4b21--a6ea--f8e17a322d5c-osd--data--6b1e779c--a18a--4e4d--960e--73ca9473d02f 253:3    0  1.2T  0 lvm
```

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This alert is for your monitor disk space that is stored normally in `/var/lib/ceph/mon`. This path is stored in root fs that isn't related to your OSDs block device. This warn is raised when this path has less than 30% available space (see `mon_data_avail_warn` which is 30 by default).
You can change it to ignore alert or resize that path to have more space for its RocksDB data.

Answer (score 1):

As Seena explained, it was because the available space is less than 30%, in this case, you could compact the mon data by the command as follow.

```
ceph tell mon.`hostname -s` compact
```

There is another way to trigger the data compaction for mon, add the mon config to the ceph.conf, and then restart the mon.

```
[mon]
 mon compact on start = true
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other folks said earlier, it's because of your node capacity,

Those Nodes that `mons` are deployed there are kind of full.

Here is the actual solution:

- It's mainly because of your unused Docker images.
- By deleting those, you save plenty of space.
- Before we start, you should install the `crictl` tool

---

Create a config file for `crictl` in `/etc/crictl.yaml`:

```
runtime-endpoint: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
image-endpoint: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
timeout: 10
debug: true
```

Then run below command:

```bash
sudo crictl --config=/etc/crictl.yaml rmi --prune
```

---

It save a lot of space and the wornings goes away.

Also, you can put this command in your Cronfile to automatically clean nodes once in a while.